# How do I prove that a function is not differentiable at 1

Tags: derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

The following function is continuous but cannot be differentiated at x=1 
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac13 x^3 + \frac12 x^2   &&\text{if } x\ge 1  \\
x- \frac16 &&\text{if } x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

If we take a sequence $\lim h_n = 0$ and suppose $h_n$ > $0$ then
 $$\lim \frac{f(1+h_n) - f(1)} {h_n} $$

I don't know where to from here, if I plug in values from $f(x)$ I will get the same limit from each equation.

Thank you.

Comment: You actually shouldn't find the same limit for each equation. Try to show that the RHS derivative, $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(1+h\right)^{3}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+h\right)^{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}1^{3}+\frac{1}{2}1^{2}\right)}{h}$, and the LHS derivative, $\frac{\left(\left(1-h\right)-\frac{1}{6}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)}{h}$ are not equal, where $h$ is positive. You can simplify both expressions quite neatly and then observe their behaviour as $h\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

$h_n$ positive accounts for only one side of the function. You must also consider the case where $h_n$ is negative, and compute the derivative (limit) under this assumption. When $h_n<0$ the definition of $f$ changes, and you should find that you get a different limit from the $h_n>0$ case, which shows non-differentiability.